# What is MySQL default mode setting?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-mode

I ‘m using MySQL 5.7.8. I find this document https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html and it said that

*The default SQL mode in MySQL 5.7 includes these modes: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, and NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.*

But when I run: SET sql_mode = default, and run: SELECT @@sql_mode, the result show only 3 setting STRICT_TRAN_TABLES, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

So, I want to know what is exactly sql_mode default setting in MySQL version 5.7?

Comment: You must have overridden the default in your MySQL Server's `my.cnf` options file. The default documented in the manual is the default if you don't set the option in your options file.

Comment: I just download and install MyySQL, and didn’t override anything in my.cnf file